# Storing range reference in a global variable

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I'm using several named ranges located in different worksheets. I need to read from and write to those ranges in many situations throughout my VBA code.

So my question is: **what is the proper way to store those range references in global variables for quick access? Or is there a better way?**

I tried declaring global variables:

```
Public WS_BOARD As Worksheet
Public RNG_BOARD As Range
```

and initializing them on `Workbook_Open`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set WS_BOARD = Worksheets("BOARD")
    Set RNG_BOARD = WS_BOARD.Range("NR_BOARD")
End Sub
```

This works okay except that if my code crashes those global variables are reset to `Nothing` and cannot be used any further (i.e. in worksheet event handlers).

Of course, I can always use something like

```
Worksheets("BOARD").Range("NR_BOARD")
```

everywhere in my code but I think it will affect performance because it obviously needs to lookup objects using string names, let alone it being not DRY.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to "load" them once into memory and then **pass them as arguments** into other subs/functions.
[Passing Variables By Reference And By Value](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/byrefbyval.aspx)

Second, you can declare them as **module-scope variables** (something like public, but only in the module you declare them).
[Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141693)

Third, **your way**.
[Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141693)

Answer (score 0):

Every worksheet has a Name property (the tab caption) and a CodeName property. If you use the CodeName in your code, you don't need a variable. Like a userform, a sheet's code name is auto instantiated when you use it.  Select the worksheet under your project in the Project Explorer (Ctrl+R), go to the Propeties (F4) and change the `(Name)` to a meaninful CodeName. The Project Explorer will then show the sheet as

```
wshDataEntry (Data Entry)
```

if you made the CodeName `wshDataEntry` and the tab said `Data Entry`.

For Ranges, I used defined names in the spreadsheet. It's like a global variable that never goes out of scope. If you have, say, and interest rate cell that you need to read in various procedure, name it Interest_Rate. Then at the top of every procedure where you need it

```
Set rInterest = wshDataEntry.Range(gsNMINTEREST)
```

where `gsNMINTEREST` is a global string variable holding "Interest_Rate". If the cell ever moves, you only need to move your named range for the code to work. If you change the name to "LiborPlusFour" you only need to update your global variable. Pretty DRY.

Yes there is a slight performance hit making VBA look up the named range every time. I wouldn't worry about that unless you've calculated a performance problem and identified it as the drag.

One way that I keep global variables (of course I'm very judicious using them) in scope is an Initialize procedure.

```
Public Sub Initialize()

    If gclsApp Is Nothing Then
        Set gclsApp = New CApp
        'do some other setup
    End If

End Sub
```

Then I call the Initialize procedure at the top of any module I need it. If it's Not Nothing, then it doesn't reset the variable. I'm not sure the performance implications of checking for Nothing and just looking up a named range, though.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are generally not a good idea. In some cases they're necessary, but this isn't one of those cases.

I don't think you should worry about the performance impact of looking up a few ranges by their string name. I have sheets with hundreds of named ranges, and I have never, *ever* observed this having a negative impact on performance.

Do you have specific evidence indicating that this is slowing down your code? If not, then don't waste time worrying about it.

I often do this to define ranges:

```
Type RangesType
    board As Range
    plank As Range
    wood As Range
End Type

Function GetRanges() As RangesType
    With GetRanges
        Set .board = Range("board")
        Set .plank = Range("plank")
        Set .wood = Range("wood")
    End With
End Function
```

Then I use them like this:

```
Sub something()
    Dim rngs As RangesType: rngs = GetRanges

    rngs.board = "My favourite board"
    rngs.wood = "Chestnut"
    'etc.

End Sub
```

Yes, ranges will get fetched by their name repeatedly if you have many subs, and no, this isn't likely to have any noticeable effect on performance.